# Expected <document start>, but found <scalar> google-ads.yaml file error Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I'm trying to setup a basic google ads api call using their quickstart docs.

I've been trying to get the google-ads.yaml file to load and work but I keep getting the error - expected , but found .

Not really sure where to go from here as i'm using the reference documentation.

```
-# OAuth2 configuration
- 
#
-# The below configuration parameters are used to authenticate using the       
#
-# recommended OAuth2 flow. For more information on authenticating with 
OAuth2 #
-# see: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/overview       
#
- 
#
developer_token: -------------
client_id: --------------------
client_secret: -----------
refresh_token: ----------------------

-# Login customer ID configuration
- 
#
-# Required for manager accounts only: Specify the login customer ID used 
to   #
-# authenticate API calls. This will be the customer ID of the 
authenticated   #
-# manager account. It should be set without dashes, for example: 
1234567890   #
-# instead of 123-456-7890. You can also specify this later in code if 
your    #
-# application uses multiple manager account + OAuth pairs.                    
#
- 
#
login_customer_id: -----------------

-# Service Account configuration
-
#
-# To authenticate with a service account add the appropriate values to 
the    #
-# below configuration parameters and remove the four OAuth credentials 
above. #
-# The "path_to_private_key_file" value should be a path to your local 
 private #
-# key json file, and "delegated_account" should be the email address that 
is  #
-# being used to impersonate the credentials making requests. for more         
#
-# information on service accounts, see:                                       
#
-# https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/service- 
accounts    #
-
#
-# path_to_private_key_file: INSERT_PATH_TO_JSON_KEY_FILE_HERE
-# delegated_account: INSERT_DOMAIN_WIDE_DELEGATION_ACCOUNT

# Logging configuration
#
# Below you may specify the logging configuration. This will be provided 
as   #
# an input to logging.config.dictConfig. Use the "level" block under the 
root #
# logger configuration to adjust the logging level. Note in the "format"      
#
# field that log messages are truncated to 5000 characters by default. You    
#
# can change this to any length by removing the ".5000" portion or 
changing   #
# it to a different number.                                                   
#
# 
# logging:
  # version: 1
  # disable_existing_loggers: False
  # formatters:
    # default_fmt:
      # format: '[%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s] %(message).5000s'
      # datefmt: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
  # handlers:
    # default_handler:
      # class: logging.StreamHandler
      # formatter: default_fmt
  # loggers:
    # "":
      # handlers: [default_handler]
      # level: INFO
```

If anyone has a better reference point for quick starts for the google ads api I would appreciate having them.

It seems that some of the reference documentation, that Google provides, is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at some example `google-ads.yaml` file, or the YAML specificiation?
The latter clearly states that a comment must be separated from other tokens by whitespace characters. So your

```
# OAuth2 configuration
```

on the first line is not a comment, because it is not separated from the sequence item indicator (`-`).

Also the example that you get when googling google-ads.yaml + reference is a file that has a mapping at the top level, and yours is a single scalar string (because of the lack of space before the octothorp/hash). Even with the comments corrected your root level would be a sequence, with the first item being `null`/`None`.

Maybe you should have a look at [this](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/googleads.yaml)